# Replace ArcGIS service files while scripting into the server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

I have an ArcGIS service into my Portal (10.3), also I have an script that replace directly into the database where those files are stored.

The problem is that when I run the script I see a blend of the past last layer with the new layer.

The output is

```
output = "C:/arcgisserver/directories/arcgissystem/arcgisinput/pronosticos/pronosticos_db.MapServer/extracted/v101/pronosticos.gdb"
```

The replacement is made with a simple clic

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis("gfs_precip_gis_48_"+ date + ".shp", clip, output + "/precipitacion_48horas")
```

Also I set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well reading a lot I could found that this will never work, but what I wanted to do is posible with arcpy.StageService_server and arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server and is solve